# angular - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: URLSearchParams in http://localhost:9877src/test.ts

Tags: angular, jasmine

This is my function in ts file.

```
getFeatures () {
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams();
    ...
}
```

This is my jasmine file.

```
 it('should get features', inject([FeatureSupportService], (service : FeatureSupportService) => {
    expect(service.getFeatures()).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Error: I am not getting this error in karma but I am getting this error when I try to code coverage with `yarn test`

```
Can't find variable: URLSearchParams in http://localhost:9877src/test.ts
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with Ionic 2 framework recently. For me it was that PhantomJS needed a polyfill for `URLSearchParams`.

So try including it as a npm package (or manually from https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params):

```
npm install url-search-params
```

And include it to whatever test runner or environment you are using e.g. karma config file:

```
files: [
            '../node_modules/url-search-params/build/url-search-params.js',
            { pattern: './karma-test-shim.js', watched: true }
        ],
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, at least generally speaking! I usually use Chrome and not PhantomJS, so when I switched over to Phantom I started seeing these errors pop up. When I swapped back they disappeared.